# Why I can't install node-sass?

Tags: node.js, json, npm, node-sass

When I type (`npm install node-sass --save-dev`) I can see:

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! path D:\Kodilla\task-runner/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token "}" (0x7D) in JSON at position 550 while prsing near "...act -o css sass\",\n  },\n  \"keywords\": [],..."
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse JSON data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note: package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Michał\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-23T10_27_32_43Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error message says it all. You have a trailing comma in your package.json file at "css sass\"," <-- trailing comma... line 550

Comment: I usually happens when you manually edit your package.json file and delete the last line in an object but forgot to delete the comma from the line before

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks @slebetman